# Deactivate iOS & Android Store from Stores but make it resetable

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, publish

I have a question regarding the Android Play Store & The Apple App Store:

Because a customer of us doesn't pay in time, we need to remove his app from the two app stores until he pays.

As soon as his payment was fulfilled, we want to put it back. Is there any possibility to do that?

I've found two options:

- For the Apple Store: Put it on State "Developer Removed from Sale"
- For Play Store: Unpublish Application

Now the question is: Can i put the apps back to sale in this states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about apple store. Answer is yes in case of Android. I just logged into my developer console and could see "Republish app" in one of my old unpublished apps.